# JavaScript Firebase Cloud Messaging Client App: not receiving notifications in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am experiencing the following behaviour: web notifications are received in firefox, however, not in google chrome.

To reproduce the issue, I have downloaded the Firebase quickstart-js repo (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js.git) and replaced the initialization config. Then started a local webserver with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`.

Using the tokens displayed both in chrome and firefox, I sent a Downstream HTTP messages (JSON) to firebase:

**With multiple registration ids:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=<KEY>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "notification": {
    "title": "Background Message Title",
    "body": "Background message body",
    "click_action" : "https://dummypage.com"
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "registration_ids" : ["<TOKEN-FIREFOX>", "<TOKEN-CHROME>"]
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

**With a single id:**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=<KEY>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "notification": {
    "title": "Background Message Title",
    "body": "Background message body",
    "click_action" : "https://dummypage.com"
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "to" : "<TOKEN-FIREFOX || TOKEN-CHROME>"
}' "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

The message arrived on the firefox client and is logged to the console, however, the chrome client did not receive any message. I have tried this with firebase versions 3.5.3 and 3.6.0.

Comment: anyone? it remains an issue even in `3.61`

Comment: What response did you get?

Comment: @idan the issue has not been resolved yet.

Comment: do you mean that the `onHandleBackgroundMessgae` callback is not being called? Because I have the same issue, but I do get a notification

Comment: @Stefan This is still an issue with 3.6.10.  I'm sending data messages through FCM HTTP endpoint (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) to my web app. In Firefox, I get the data message immediately.  In Google Chrome, I never see anything. I did notice that the message_id is formatted differently between the two browsers.  When pushing to Firefox, I see the following in the message_id string: `https:\/\/updates.push.services.mozilla.com`. Both report success in the response of the HTTP POST to FCM.